# Laptop freezes completely and randomly

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, freeze, hardware-failure

I have a custom made laptop with [these specifications](https://www.bto.eu/bto-x-book-15cl73.html) using the Core i7 option and running Windows 10 Pro.

When I first bought it, it had a problem that the screen kept flickering which I told Intel about in [this thread](https://communities.intel.com/thread/91353?start=0&tstart=0).

After that they released a driver that combined with Microsoft's updates solved the flickering screen problem.

Now I have a problem that the laptop freezes completely at random times, and I mean freeze as in the screen just displays the last thing it was on and you can't do anything, literally you can't do anything. Pressing any button like <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> doesn't even turn the <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> light on.

I can't do anything and no matter how much I wait it remains in that state.

One final thing. I have been getting this warning in the event viewer since I got the machine:

> The speed of processor x in group 0 is being limited by system
>   firmware. The processor has been in this reduced performance state for
>   71 seconds since the last report.

Where x goes from 0 to 7.

The only way to solve it is by pressing the power button and shutting it down and then starting again.

I don't know if the graphics driver could be causing this and thus my questions are:

1. Could a device driver cause this severe issue ?
2. Is there anyway to get a lead on this as the log files don't show anything whatsoever and no matter how much I wait it remains frozen ?
3. In other words, is there any to figure out why this is happening so I can solve it ?

**NOTE:** I have tried [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) software and the RAMs are working fine.

Comment: I can't really answer your last two questions, but I would say that a single device driver is unlikely to cause _this_ kind of severe issue. Typically you would get a BSoD or the whole device would stop functioning, but it wouldn't impact other devices (such as the keyboard, as you mentioned). Still, I don't know if it's possible to completely rule out the possibility of an issue with a single driver.

Comment: @fakedad thank you. But for whomever who voted this down, could you please explain why so I can ask the correct questions next time ?

Comment: Down votes are opinions, nothing more. It does not mean it is a bad question.

Comment: if CAPSLOCK doesn't toggle the light, you have a hardware issue and no software problem. Check your HW (memtest86+ for RAM and prime95 for your CPU).

Comment: @magicandre1981The weird thing is that I didn't have the freezing issue before. It only surfaced when the original problem with the flickering screen was solved.

Comment: I must say that I have forced my computer into this state (cap locks light frozen) many times through the use of bad software (linux kernel crashes, hackintosh, etc...). Have you tried setting any of your drivers to use windows 7 or windows 8 mode?

Comment: Also, have you seen this thread which mentions disabling the powersave function in the realtek audio card to prevent screen flickering? This is supposed to apply to windows 10 as well: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/disable-windows-7-audio-power-management/c3953ef8-ce14-4f55-9058-f6e2c8eae3fe?auth=1

Comment: @mchid I haven't tried to set the drivers to work in Windows 7 nor Windows 8 mode. For now I have disabled the the ability for the driver to be put to sleep by the system. I will try this for a while and then try other steps.